# IOS/xcode/Core Foundation: If a value is null do you have to release it?

Tags: core-foundation

my app has been crashing on releasing values pulled from an address book that turned out to be null

Is it okay to only release if the value is not null or do you always have to release?

```
 CFStringRef firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(lRef,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    //    CFRelease(firstName);// this was causing crash


if(firstName!=NULL) {

    CFRelease(firstName);

}
```

Newb to core foundation so appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the argument is NULL, `CFRelease` will cause a runtime error and your application will crash.

If the retain count of `CFTypeRef` objects becomes zero the memory allocated to the object is deallocated and the object is destroyed. If you create, copy, or explicitly retain (see the CFRetain function) a Core Foundation object, you are responsible for releasing it when you no longer need it.

so yes, you should only call `CFRelease` if `firstName` is not NULL when you no longer need it.